# Why adding more rows in table moves the table in 2nd page?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0cm,top=0cm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\aline}{\\\hline \arabic{theyflines} &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\rule{0cm}{.4cm}}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{theyflines}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.20cm}|p{2.75cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{0.35cm}|p{2.60cm}|p{1.30cm}|p{1.30cm}|}
\hline
SL&Name& Room&Dept.&L&D&B&L&D&B&L&D&B&L&Deposit&Cost&Extra
\forloop{theyflines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 48}{\aline}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

When I extend rows `48` to `55` then the table moves to 2nd pages instead of 1st page. Why?

Comment: Because tables do not do page-breaking?!

Comment: 47 table rows are too much... unless they have a height of 1pt only ;-) Besides that, you will run into issues with `\foreach` inside of tables

Comment: @TeXnician My concern is which fit in 2nd page without breaking, why this doesn't fit in 1st page?

Comment: It does not fit on the second page either, but LaTeX refuses to try further to move such a long table. If you try 56 rows you won't see all of them on the second page.

Comment: latex does warn in some detail  that the table is too wide `Overfull \hbox (4.30957pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--10`  and too tall `Overfull \vbox (94.73114pt too high) has occurred while \output is active` to fit in (any) page.

Comment: @TeXnician yes. You are right. My observation was wrong.